# How to show full git log in terminal?

Tags: git

I need to list the full log from the most recent recent commit to the first commit. So far I tried all the below and nothing works. I only get a [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) view showing the most recent 2-3 commits.

```
git log --full-history
```

and

```
git log --full-diff
```

and

```
git log -n 999999
```

and

```
git log --before yesterday
```

and

```
git log --full-diff --sparse
```

and

```
git log --reflog
```

and

```
git log --grep *.*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to display the git log from the earliest commit to the most recent, you can view it in reverse order using `git log --reverse`. This will show all commits by default. To skip the pager (`less`), you can use `git --no-pager log --reverse`.

Comment: I get: `fatal: ambiguous argument '–reverse': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: Ah, I've got an em dash instead of hyphen in my example, I'll edit.

Comment: I'm on macOS if this makes any difference. Anyway the `--no-pager` flag did the trick.